How to Fix 'The metadata storage is not up to date' Error in Symfony with Doctrine ORM and Migrations?
How can I resolve the 'The metadata storage is not up to date' error in Symfony when using Doctrine ORM and migrations? I added a new entity to my Symfony application, and when I ran 'php bin/console make:migration', I encountered this error. I've already tried running 'php bin/console doctrine:migrations:sync-metadata-storage', but the problem persists. How can I properly synchronize Doctrine metadata with my database and fix this error
and i'm useing symfony 7
I first ran 'php bin/console doctrine:migrations:sync-metadata-storage' to synchronize Doctrine metadata with my database. I expected this command to update the metadata storage and resolve any discrepancies between my entities and the database schema.
After that, I generated a new migration using 'php bin/console make:migration' to capture the changes made to my entities. I expected this command to generate a migration file that reflects the changes I made and can be applied to the database.
Finally, I attempted to apply the migration using 'php bin/console doctrine:migrations:migrate'. I expected this command to execute the migration and update my database schema accordingly.

This usually happens when you redact the database directly, try deleting the database and executing the make:migration command again, this should resolve any differences.
